# How Do You Use curve_fit in Python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am using curve_fit (from `scipy.optimze`) to solve the following:

my y axis is

```
si = np.log([426.0938, 259.2896, 166.8042, 80.9248])
```

my x axis is

```
b = np.array([50,300,600,1000])
```

I am doing log the y axis because my original equation is

```
si = exp(b * a)
```

I want to calculate a but I assume that it is the slope of the curve?

```
def fun(x,a):
 return np.dot(x,a)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,b,si)
print(popt)
[1.]
```

I really don't understand how to use the popt data obtained from curve_fit in my equation.

Comment: Why are you using `dot`? You want the theoretical y-values, not the sum of them...

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are right, it does not make sense. But using dot in this case (in which is used only a value at time) will not change the outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but popt is basically the extimated value of a. In your case it is the value of the slope of a linear function which starts from 0 (without intercept value):

```
f(x) = a*x
```

because it will not fit correctly the data, it would be better to use linear function with an intercept value:

```
f(x) = a*x + b
```

defined as such:

```
def fun(x,a,b):
    return a * x + b
```

Basically, after running your example, you will obtain the best parameters (a the slope and b the intercept) for your linear function to fit your example data.
Below the full example with the results:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

# e^(a * b)
e_exp_a_x_b = [426.0938, 259.2896, 166.8042, 80.9248]
# a * b
a_x_b = np.log(e_exp_a_x_b)
# b
b = np.array([50,300,600,1000])

def fun(x,a_slope,b_intercept):
    return a_slope * x + b_intercept

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
x_data = b
y_data = a_x_b

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun, b, a_x_b)
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, label='Data')
plt.plot(x_data, fun(x_data, popt[0], popt[1]),
         label='Fitted function')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: I am doing a mono exponential fit for a signal decay (si) at increasing diffusion gradients (b). It should be linear and could be easily fitted using two points in a single equation. But the measured signal is usually contaminated by noise and the fit is more accurate when multiple points are used. so in a perfect world the points should fit a straight line. I think your proposed solution is good for my case. I will give it a try.

Comment: values at b0 were excluded in purpose (related to the physiological process measured with the signal decay), I don't want to force the line to intercept with the y axis.

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I want, the slope :) , I have a large data set as a numpy array 38X240X240, I was using just one point as my si array. Should I do this point by point through a loop or can I use the whole array in curve_fit?

Comment: I think that you can use all your dataset. Anyway if you have problems it is better to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you first visually inspect a scatterplot of the data you would pass to curve_fit(), you would see (as in the answer of @Nikaido) that the data appears to lie on a straight line. Here is a graphical Python fitter similar to that provided by @Nikaido:

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# the "dtype=float" ensures floating point numbers,
# otherwise this would be a numpy array of integers
b = numpy.array([50,300,600,1000], dtype=float)

# these are already floating point numbers
si = numpy.log([426.0938, 259.2896, 166.8042, 80.9248])

# alias data names to match previous example code
xData = b
yData = si

def func(x, slope, offset):
    return slope * x + offset


# same as the scipy defaults
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```